# Error ID is null when should be auto-incremented

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a web form that allows a user to add an item to a database. Problem is when I submit said form I get the following error:

Field error in object 'products' on field 'id': rejected value [null]; codes [typeMismatch.products.id,typeMismatch.id,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch]; arguments

Here's my jsp page:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Item Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Add an Item </h1>
    <form action="/addItem" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type = "text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="2" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input class="form-control" type = "text" id="price" name="price" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="foodGroup">Food Group</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="foodGroup" name="foodgroup" required>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">Add Product</button>
        </form>
            <a href="/" class="btn btn-secondary">Home</a>
</body>
```

Here's the relevant part of my Products class (the rest is typical getter/setter/toString. I also left out the package line at the top):

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Products
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    String name;
    String foodgroup;
    int quantity;
    Float price;
    String image;

    private Products() {}

    public Products(int id, String name, int quantity, float price, String foodgroup, String image)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.foodgroup = foodgroup;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

and finally the controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController
{

    @Autowired
    private ProductsDAO productsDAO;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView showHome()
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showProducts")
    public ModelAndView showProducts()
    {
        List<Products> leListOfProducts = productsDAO.findAll();
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("showProducts", "product", leListOfProducts);
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/addItem")
    public ModelAndView showAddItemPage()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("addItem");
    }

    @PostMapping("/addItem")
    public ModelAndView addProduct(Products product)
    {
        productsDAO.create(product);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index");
    }
}
```

Here's a pic of the table columns and their settings. [image: SQL DB Columns]

I really appreciate any and all help ya'll can provide!

Best,

JBird

Comment: I suspect that your constructor is the issue there. Try removing the id in the constructor, as it is being generated by 3rd party means. Also, I don't think you will ever need the setId() method for any sane reason.

Comment: That was it! :) Thanks for your help!
@IvanDimitrov can you post your comment as an answer? If you do I can credit you for the answer and mark this thread as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your constructor is the issue there. Try removing the id in the constructor, as it is being generated by 3rd party means. Also, I don't think you will ever need the setId() method for any sane reason.